# Issue querying Google Places API on React Native for iOS

Tags: react-native, google-places-api, react-native-ios, google-maps-sdk-ios, react-native-maps

When using react-native-maps on my React Native iOS application, running Expo locally via the Expo app or an iOS Simulator everything works great. The API calls are working to receive places, nearby locations, and the rest of the Google API suite.

When I build the app using `expo build:ios` and upload the generated .IPA file using Transporter on MacOS to TestFlight - I install the app from TestFlight on my phone and the react-native-maps works, but all my markers are gone, and no results are returned when making a nearby API call or a places search.

Here's my MapView setup:

```
const mapMarkerIcon = require('../../../assets/images/icons/mapMarker/mapMarker.png');

<MapView
    ref={(ref) => this._map = ref}
    onRegionChangeComplete={(region) => { this.onRegionChangeComplete(region) }}
    onMapReady={() => { this.initMap() }}
    showsUserLocation={true}
    loadingEnabled={true}
    style={{
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
        height: Dimensions.get('window').height / 2,
    }}>
    {this.props.pharmacies && this.props.pharmacies.map((pharm, index) => (
        <Marker
            coordinate={pharm.coordinates}
            key={index}
            title={pharm.name}
            tracksViewChanges={false}
            onPress={this.onMarkerPress(pharm.coordinates)}
            onCalloutPress={() => { console.log(pharm) }}
            image={mapMarkerIcon}
        >
        </Marker>

    ))}
</MapView>
```

App.json:

```
"ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX", //HIDDEN ON PURPOSE
      "config": {
        "googleMapsApiKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      },
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSFaceIDUsageDescription": "This app will optionally use Face ID or Touch ID to save login"
      },
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
```

Again, this works great when running locally, on the Expo App or a Simulator running the Expo app, but does not work and returns no results when publishing to TestFlight.

**Running on Expo App/Locally**
[image: Running on Expo App/Locally]
**After installing from TestFlight/Published to App Store Connect**
[image: After installing from TestFlight/Published to App Store Connect]

Comment: Are there any errors thrown from your logs? How does the map looks like on TestFlight? Have you also checked if your Google Maps API key are using any restrictions?

Comment: Be aware that on local you are using Expo client, which will have a different bundle id than your own built app's bundle id

Comment: As @Pagemag suggested, check your Google console for errors. Maybe your API key is not enabled for production, like you need to add billing details, etc...

Comment: Where pharmacies comes from? How are you filling the 'pharmacies' props?

Comment: Pharmacies are coming from the Places API. We make a request within a specific radius, querying the types: ["pharmacy", "drugstore"].

I have confirmed the bundle ID is not the issue. 

No errors in logs that I was able to find on Google end. I believe it may be API key related, and I may have to enable it for production like @colakollektiv said. But I am unsure as to how to do that vs using an API key for development, so I will do some more researching.

Comment: Have you checked your restrictions on your key? Your key also has logs that may give some insight. It will show if there have been requests and such. 

If you have your restrictions wide open and stuff is showing up in your logs I'm of little help. If not please report back with status :)

Comment: @TallOrderDev Tested setting on restrictions for iOS apps only along with the right bundle ID. I even went as far as not restricting the key. Tried using Google as the provider for the maps instead of Apple Maps and still no luck. Works great running locally on expo, but fails when push to TestFlight and downloaded from TestFlight app. The logs for the key do show up on the requests chart, looks like a 4xx error, good place to start digging deeper.